# SQL Query convert nvarchar to datetime while joining

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, join

I have two tables, that contain event type information. One has its date and time stamp set up correctly, i.e. using datetime, the other has nvarchar.
I can't change the column definitions.

I want to join these tables in a query with both time stamp columns.

I've a sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7e1be

I thought this would work:

```
select 
  Event1.Col1, Event1.EventDateTime1, 
  Event2.Col2, convert(datetime,Event1.EventDateTime1,121) as EventDateTime21

from Event1 FULL OUTER JOIN EVENT2 
  on Event1.EventDateTime1 = EventDateTime21
```

But my very basic knowledge of sql is failing me!

How do i make my column EventDateTime21 exist?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Der

Comment: Looking at the fiddle: The times are different and initial column has an 'X' in the middle. How do the rows correspond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CONVERT` so you can use the correct data format (in this case, it would be 121):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Event1 E1
INNER JOIN dbo.Event2 E2
    ON E1.EventDateTime1 = CONVERT(DATETIME,E2.EventDateTime2,121);
```

Anyway, the dates don't match, so the query gives zero results

Comment: Thank you!   I want to show events from two different logs in one view so I'm using FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that all the strings are valid dates:

```
from A inner join B on cast(B.date_column as datetime) = A.date_column
```

Based on your fiddle one possible correspondence is:

```
select *
from Event1 e1 inner join Event2 e2
    on e2.Col2 = stuff(e1.Col1, 4, 0, 'X')
```

Another possibility that does use the timestamps:

```
with e1 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by EventDateTime1) as rn
), e2 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by EventDateTime2) as rn
)
select *
from e1 inner join e2
    on e2.rn = e1.rn
```

*EDIT: After your update to the question and comment on accepted answer:*

I think you really want a union. It will be much faster than a join with two columns that never match and a cast in the join condition.

```
select Col1 as Col, EventDateTime1 as EventDateTime from Event1
union all
select Col2, convert(datetime, EventDateTime2, 121) from Event2
```

Comment: Check data they are different (no direct match)

Comment: @shawnt00  This is a noob question, but if I'm using SQL Builder to make my queries in SQL Server 2008 how do I construct the union?  You can ignore this if you want, I'll keep googleing! Thanks again. My DB actually has lots of this type of thing happening.

Comment: Sometimes those query builders don't let you do unions. And then sometimes it will still represent a query that you couldn't have built through the interface. So you should be able to drop in the SQL on the SQL pane although you may not be able to edit much at that point.